# Access different element of matrix at the same time python :: error of index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, slice, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to access different elements at the same time in a numpy matrix in python:
however, I got the following error "line 5, in  z=y_1[x_1[i,:],0]
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4"
I understand it can not be used 4 elements , however, is there a way to do so to get the results below ... like a way in a matlab ?

```
import numpy as np 
x_1=np.array([[1,3,4,2]])
y_1=np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[20,0,0],[20,0,1]])
for i in range (1):
    z=y_1[x_1[i,:],0]
#z should be z=[[0],[20],[20],[0]]
```

way in matlab:

```
clc
x_1=[1 3 4 2]
y_1=[0 0 0;0 0 1;20 0 0;20 0 1]
for i = 1:size(x_1,1)
    z = y_1(x_1(i,:),1)
end
```

Comment: In python, index starts with 0, i.e., you need to change `x_1` as well. You are accessing index 4 because of the third element of `x_1`, which does not exist in `y_1`.

Comment: @j1-lee
Thank you for your comment, 
however this does not change any thing, I am already considering  that

Comment: Also `range 1` is not a valid expression.

Comment: @j1-lee
thank you again, I edited the question, 
But I would kindly ask you to run the code, as those are not the problem,

Comment: I think you would be better served by working through a Numpy tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Python indices are 0-based. Therefore you need to modify the 'index' vector `x_1` as well. Try the following:

```py
import numpy as np 
# x_1 = np.array([[1,3,4,2]]) # no, python is 0-based
x_1 = np.array([0, 2, 3, 1])
y_1 = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [20,0,0], [20,0,1]])

z = y_1[x_1, 0]
print(z) # [ 0 20 20  0]
```

If you want to have `z` as a column vector, you can either reshape it by `z = z = y_1[x_1, 0].reshape((-1, 1))` or reshape the `x_1` at the beginning: `x_1 = np.array([[0], [2], [3], [1]])`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, 
I got what you mentioned earlier, however, those values x_1 and y_1 will be generated automatically, so and the dimensions (size will not be fixed) 
so is there a way to do so more dynamically as I attached in matlab ??

Comment: As for `x_1`, you can just put `x_1 -= 1` after you get something like `[1, 3, 4, 2]`.

Comment: As for the size, I don't understand it. Isn't it tru that the length of `x_1` equals to the number of rows of `y_1`? If it is the case, `z = y_1[x_1, 0]` would take care of it automatically. Otherwise, I don't know how you would handle the discrepancy.